# Query Database Using a Form with Multiple Fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with radio buttons that I want to use to get data from a table in a MySQL database and this is the form:

```
<div class="filter-container">
<p class="filter-title">BTU's</p><div class="filter">
<input type="radio" name="choice-0" id="choice-0" tabindex="0" value="" checked="checked" />
<label for="none">None</label></div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-0" id="choice-0" tabindex="0" value="100000" />
    <label for="choice-0">100000<span>(10)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-0" id="choice-0" tabindex="0" value="120000" />
    <label for="choice-0">120000<span>(7)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-0" id="choice-0" tabindex="0" value="40000" />
    <label for="choice-0">40000<span>(5)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-0" id="choice-0" tabindex="0" value="60000" />
    <label for="choice-0">60000<span>(11)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-0" id="choice-0" tabindex="0" value="80000" />
    <label for="choice-0">80000<span>(18)</span></label>
    </div></div><div class="filter-container">
<p class="filter-title">Efficiency (AFUE)</p><div class="filter">
<input type="radio" name="choice-1" id="choice-1" tabindex="0" value="" checked="checked" />
<label for="none">None</label></div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-1" id="choice-1" tabindex="1" value="80%" />
    <label for="choice-1">80%<span>(21)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-1" id="choice-1" tabindex="1" value="92%" />
    <label for="choice-1">92%<span>(8)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-1" id="choice-1" tabindex="1" value="96%" />
    <label for="choice-1">96%<span>(17)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-1" id="choice-1" tabindex="1" value="97%" />
    <label for="choice-1">97%<span>(5)</span></label>
    </div></div><div class="filter-container">
<p class="filter-title">Width</p><div class="filter">
<input type="radio" name="choice-2" id="choice-2" tabindex="0" value="" checked="checked" />
<label for="none">None</label></div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-2" id="choice-2" tabindex="2" value="14" />
    <label for="choice-2">14<span>(4)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-2" id="choice-2" tabindex="2" value="17.5" />
    <label for="choice-2">17.5<span>(20)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-2" id="choice-2" tabindex="2" value="21" />
    <label for="choice-2">21<span>(19)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-2" id="choice-2" tabindex="2" value="221" />
    <label for="choice-2">221<span>(1)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-2" id="choice-2" tabindex="2" value="24.5" />
    <label for="choice-2">24.5<span>(7)</span></label>
    </div></div><div class="filter-container">
<p class="filter-title">Blower Type</p><div class="filter">
<input type="radio" name="choice-3" id="choice-3" tabindex="0" value="" checked="checked" />
<label for="none">None</label></div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-3" id="choice-3" tabindex="3" value="Multi-Speed" />
    <label for="choice-3">Multi-Speed<span>(23)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-3" id="choice-3" tabindex="3" value="Multi-Speed ECM" />
    <label for="choice-3">Multi-Speed ECM<span>(7)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-3" id="choice-3" tabindex="3" value="Single Speed" />
    <label for="choice-3">Single Speed<span>(7)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-3" id="choice-3" tabindex="3" value="Variable Speed" />
    <label for="choice-3">Variable Speed<span>(3)</span></label>
    </div><div class="filter">
    <input type="radio" name="choice-3" id="choice-3" tabindex="3" value="Variable Speed ECM" />
    <label for="choice-3">Variable Speed ECM<span>(11)</span></label>
    </div></div>
```

I need to match any combination of values with a category constant.  This is what I am using to process the form:

```
<?php
if('POST' == htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) ){

    $cat_id = 4001;

    if ( isset($_POST['choice-0']) ) {
        $choice0 = $_POST['choice-0'];
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['choice-1']) ) {
        $choice1 = $_POST['choice-1'];
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['choice-2']) ) {
        $choice2 = $_POST['choice-2'];
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['choice-3']) ) {
        $choice3 = $_POST['choice-3'];
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['choice-4']) ) {
        $choice4 = $_POST['choice-4'];
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['choice-5']) ) {
        $choice5 = $_POST['choice-5'];
    }

    if ( isset($_POST['choice-6']) ) {
        $choice6 = $_POST['choice-6'];
    }

    $query = $connect->query( "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PR_ProductCategory='$cat_id' AND (PR_UDSearch0='$choice0' OR PR_UDSearch1='$choice1' OR PR_UDSearch2='$choice2' OR PR_UDSearch3='$choice3' OR PR_UDSearch4='$choice4' OR PR_UDSearch5='$choice5' OR PR_UDSearch6='$choice6')" );

    var_dump($query);

}
```

?>

I have done various SELECT statements to get the data with no luck (including the one above).  I don't want a combination of matches.  For my needs I need matches from one or the other not both.  In other words, I need to use the cat_id as a constant and then match any other combination that I get from the radio buttons (choice 1, or choice 1 and 2, or choice 2 and 4, or choice 3 etc.).  I must be setting it up wrong with the query or something else.  I have googled for days and haven't figured it out yet.  Thanks!!

UPDATE:  I now am trying to create the SELECT statement based on the choices:

```
$cat_id = 4001;
                    $query_str = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PR_ProductCategory='$cat_id' AND (";

                    if ( isset($_POST['choice-0'] ) ) {
                        $choice0 = $_POST['choice-0'];
                        $query_str .= "PR_UDSearch0='$choice0'";
                    }

                    if ( isset($_POST['choice-1'] ) ) {
                        $choice1 = $_POST['choice-1'];
                        $query_str .= "OR PR_UDSearch0='$choice1'";
                    }

                    if ( isset($_POST['choice-2'] ) ) {
                        $choice2 = $_POST['choice-2'];
                        $query_str .= "OR PR_UDSearch0='$choice2'";
                    }

                    if ( isset($_POST['choice-3'] ) ) {
                        $choice3 = $_POST['choice-3'];
                        $query_str .= "OR PR_UDSearch0='$choice3'";
                    }

                    if ( isset($_POST['choice-4'] ) ) {
                        $choice4 = $_POST['choice-4'];
                        $query_str .= "OR PR_UDSearch0='$choice4'";
                    }

                    if ( isset($_POST['choice-5'] ) ) {
                        $choice5 = $_POST['choice-5'];
                        $query_str .= "OR PR_UDSearch0='$choice5'";
                    }

                    if ( isset($_POST['choice-6'] ) ) {
                        $choice6 = $_POST['choice-6'];
                        $query_str .= "OR PR_UDSearch0='$choice6'";
                    }

                    $query_str .= ")";
                    $query = $connect->query( $query_str );
```

I think it is closer but I get NULL if something is not selected.

LAST UPDATE:  I figured it out with some help.  I built the SELECT statement based on the selection and used that to get the results. This was my full solution:

```
    if('POST' == htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) ){

$cat_id = 4001;
$query_str = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PR_ProductCategory='$cat_id' ";

if ( isset($_POST['choice-0']) ) {
    $choice0 = $_POST['choice-0'];

    if ( $choice0 ) {
        $query_str .= "AND PR_UDSearch0='$choice0'";
    }
}

if ( isset($_POST['choice-1']) ) {
    $choice1 = $_POST['choice-1'];

    if ( $choice1 ) {
        $query_str .= " AND PR_UDSearch1='$choice1'";
    }
}

if ( isset($_POST['choice-2']) ) {
    $choice2 = $_POST['choice-2'];

    if ( $choice2 ) {
        $query_str .= " AND PR_UDSearch2='$choice2'";
    }
}

if ( isset($_POST['choice-3']) ) {
    $choice3 = $_POST['choice-3'];

    if ( $choice3 ) {
        $query_str .= " AND PR_UDSearch3='$choice3'";
    }
}

if ( isset($_POST['choice-4']) ) {
    $choice4 = $_POST['choice-4'];

    if ( $choice4 ) {
        $query_str .= " AND PR_UDSearch4='$choice4'";
    }
}

if ( isset($_POST['choice-5']) ) {
    $choice5 = $_POST['choice-5'];

    if ( $choice5 ) {
        $query_str .= " AND PR_UDSearch5='$choice5'";
    }
}

if ( isset($_POST['choice-6']) ) {
    $choice6 = $_POST['choice-6'];

    if ( $choice6 ) {
        $query_str .= " AND PR_UDSearch6='$choice6'";
    }
}

$query_str .= "";
$query = $connect->query( $query_str );

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

$sku    = $row[PR_SKU];
$img    = $row[PR_URLofThumb];
$desc   = $row[PR_Description];
$price  = $row[PR_UnitPrice];

echo '<div class="box">
<div class="box-image">
<a href="/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=' . $sku . '"><img src="' . $img . '" /></a>
</div>
<p>Price:' .  $price . '</p>
<a href="/cgi-bin/commerce.cgi?preadd=action&key=' . $sku . '">' . $desc . '</a>
</div>';

 }
}
```

Comment: It's probably because $choice1, $choice2, ..., $choice6 are undefined in your $query when isset($_POST['choice-1']), isset($_POST['choice_2']), ... isset($_POST['choice_6']) returns false.

Comment: can you show your product table? I am guessing the problem lies in PR_UDSearch0,PR_UDSearch1 and so on..

Comment: @Martijn - No.  I can get each value separately.  If I submit is with a choice of none (the default) I get 0 rows returned -  ["num_rows"]=> int(0) unless that is what you mean.

Comment: @jonju - The table is large, but if I run the select in the SQL tab of phpMyAdmin it works perfectly.  That is how I know I am not getting the correct results.

Comment: I am now thinking that I need to build the query based on the options selected.  Not have the query and try to add the values.  Do you think that is right?  If so, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: try echo-ing your query let's see what we get..

Comment: Is it possible that any given `PR_UDSearch#` field will contain an empty string ( `""` )?

Comment: @DFriend - Yes.  I just broke it down echoing each choice.  If there are only four choices selected they are echoed with a NULL at the end.  This must be my problem.  Not sure how to fix it yet.  I made an edit above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you may have to build the query statement based on the selections. This code will do that.

```
$cat_id = 4001;
$choices = [];

if(!empty($_POST['choice-0']))
{
  $choices[] = "PR_UDSearch0='{$_POST['choice-0']}'";
}
if(!empty($_POST['choice-1']))
{
  $choices[] = "PR_UDSearch1='{$_POST['choice-1']}'";
}
if(!empty($_POST['choice-2']))
{
  $choices[] = "PR_UDSearch2='{$_POST['choice-2']}'";
}
if(!empty($_POST['choice-3']))
{
  $choices[] = "PR_UDSearch3='{$_POST['choice-3']}'";
}
if(!empty($_POST['choice-4']))
{
  $choices[] = "PR_UDSearch4='{$_POST['choice-4']}'";
}
if(!empty($_POST['choice-5']))
{
  $choices[] = "PR_UDSearch5='{$_POST['choice-5']}'";
}
if(!empty($_POST['choice-6']))
{
  $choices[] = "PR_UDSearch6='{$_POST['choice-5']}'";
}

$additional_where = "";
$count = count($choices);

if($count > 0)
{
  if($count > 1)
  {
    $i = 0;
    $additional_where = " AND (";
    foreach($choices as $choice)
    {
      $or = ++$i < $count ? " OR " : ""; //adding OR where needed
      $additional_where .= $choice.$or;
    }
    $additional_where .= ")";
  }
  else
  {
    $additional_where = " AND $choices[0]";
  }
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS WHERE PR_ProductCategory='$cat_id'".$additional_where;

var_dump($sql);
//$query = $connect->query($sql);
//var_dump($query);
```

By using `!empty($_POST[...` you are confirming that the `$_POST` item is set, it is not NULL, and not an empty string all at once.

Comment: Thanks so MUCH!  I just figured out a solution that works before I saw this.  I posted it above.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: Looks like it will work. Other than using " AND " for the options it get's you to the same place as my answer. I'd still appreciate and up-vote :)

Comment: What I ended up with in my edit works great, thanks!  I up-voted but I am new and my reputation isn't good enough yet.  Your solution looks great. Thanks for the help!